# Fails to output correct per step in numeric range

Tags: c#

I don't know, how, can I get this to work, so that, depending on the step, it gives me correct output and amount. I know, `1000 / 10 = 100`, but, it cannot start over from `100` after `900`. What if, `1000 / 2.5` or something, depending on context.

**C# code:**

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int m_step = 10;
        int m_maximum = 1000;
        int m_minimum = 0;
        var factor = 1000 / (m_maximum - m_minimum);
        
        for(var i = m_minimum; i < m_maximum; i++){
            if(!(i % m_step == 0))
                continue;
            int v = ((m_maximum - i) * factor);
            System.Console.WriteLine(@"{0}", v);
        }
    }
}
```

**Current output:**

```
1000
990
980
970
960
950
940
930
920
910
900
890
880
870
860
850
840
830
820
810
800
790
780
770
760
750
740
730
720
710
700
690
680
670
660
650
640
630
620
610
600
590
580
570
560
550
540
530
520
510
500
490
480
470
460
450
440
430
420
410
400
390
380
370
360
350
340
330
320
310
300
290
280
270
260
250
240
230
220
210
200
190
180
170
160
150
140
130
120
110
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
```

**Desired output:**

```
1000
900
800
700
600
500
400
300
200
100
```

Comment: `2.5` won't work when you use the type `int` you will need to use a datatype that supports floating point numbers eg. `float` / `double` / `decimal` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: @RandRandom, I know, but, I just wrote as an example.

Comment: If your desired output uses 100 step, use 100 as `m_step` not 10

Comment: Looks like a homework question, but you have left out some details of what the goal/parameters are, so it is hard to give an answer that will help you understand what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, your code simply doesn't reflect what you are looking for, try this

```
int m_stepCount = 10;
int m_maximum = 1000;
int m_minimum = 0;
int m_stepSize = (m_maximum - m_minimum) / m_stepCount;

for(var i = m_stepCount; i > 0; i--)
{
    int v = i * m_stepSize;
    System.Console.WriteLine(@"{0}", v);
}
```

eg.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/KmmYPC

Answer (score 0):

Try with `int m_step = 100`, that should fix it.

Comment: What about 10 steps, 100 -> 1000, in a 10 step range?

Comment: @AlbinM - well your code doesn't say how many steps it should be but instead how big the steps should be

Comment: @AlbinM - eg. if `m_step = 25` you get this result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6M0739 - not 25 steps, but each step is 25

Comment: @RandRandom exactly